# Buy multiple products to use app on multiple devices

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, lifetime

As we all know that once we purchased apple subscription plan from a device with Apple id the same will be resume on other device if have login with that same Apple id.

But here we need that every time the user will login on different device with the same Apple id or different Apple Id, we want's the to user purchase the subscription plan. e.g., If user has purchased 2 Subscriptions then he will be able to use app on two different devices So for that we created multiple subscription products.

Can someone help how we can create multiple products for same functionality So that Apple can approve it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear,  but I think you and your users would find it easier if you tracked the number of installed devices on their account using `identifierForVendor` and provided a management screen where they could remove obsolete devices.

Comment: @Paulw11 please read again.

Comment: I read it.  I am telling you it is a bad approach.  It will be difficult to implement and confusing for the user.  Track the number of active devices against the subscription that the user has.

Comment: @Paulw11
Actually we are using our web part for the confirmation. So implementation is not the issue.
We have functionality to track the number currently logged in devices by the user and when user will try to login on the next device then they will pop-up to purchase another licence 

and whenever user purchase a Subscription(Non consumable product), that is added to the DB for that user